# Snappy & wkhtmltopdf : page numbering in footer

Tags: php, pdf, wrapper, wkhtmltopdf, snappy

I would like to have the page number in the footer of every page generated with Snappy and Wkhtmltopdf, but i haven't found any clue about it.

I can set a footer text (with options 'footer-center') but how to put the page number ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

... the doc [here](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html#Footers%20And%20Headers) indicate that some tags are replaced with, for example, the page number.

Comment: setting [page] does not work. How did the problem get solved?

Comment: I used it like this : $snappy->setOption('footer-center', 'Page [page]');

Comment: `--footer-right "Page [page] of [toPage]" --footer-font-size 8`

Comment: @user1254498 that link is dead. This one could help: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt, topic "Footers And Headers".

Answer (score 2):

Adding this as the accepted answer is just a 404 link.

Wkhtmltopdf gives us a number of options for controlling where to put the footer text, according to [the documentation](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt):

```
  --footer-center <text>          Centered footer text
  --footer-font-name <name>       Set footer font name (default Arial)
  --footer-font-size <size>       Set footer font size (default 12)
  --footer-html <url>             Adds a html footer
  --footer-left <text>            Left aligned footer text
  --footer-line                   Display line above the footer
  --no-footer-line                Do not display line above the footer
                                  (default)
  --footer-right <text>           Right aligned footer text
  --footer-spacing <real>         Spacing between footer and content in mm
                                  (default 0)
```

Within the footer (or header) you then have a number of keywords

```
* [page]       Replaced by the number of the pages currently being printed
* [frompage]   Replaced by the number of the first page to be printed
* [topage]     Replaced by the number of the last page to be printed
* [webpage]    Replaced by the URL of the page being printed
* [section]    Replaced by the name of the current section
* [subsection] Replaced by the name of the current subsection
* [date]       Replaced by the current date in system local format
* [isodate]    Replaced by the current date in ISO 8601 extended format
* [time]       Replaced by the current time in system local format
* [title]      Replaced by the title of the of the current page object
* [doctitle]   Replaced by the title of the output document
* [sitepage]   Replaced by the number of the page in the current site being converted
* [sitepages]  Replaced by the number of pages in the current site being converted
```

So for example, in order to add a running page number to the right of the page footer you can do this in KnpSnappy:

```
$snappyPdf->setOption('footer-right', '[page]');
```